# Could not create an Objective-C bridging header because the group "CameraExample" references a nonexistent location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tensorflow, bridging-header

I am a 14-year-old hobbyist, trying to implement image recognition into a basic skin disease monitoring app. To base on previous projects, I have tried importing a project from  [Tensorflow/Tensorflow/contrib/ios_examples/camera](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/ios_examples). I want to implement my own trained model to specialize on various unique skin diseases which I doubt may be the focus on other pre-trained models such as Inception, or IBM Watson, thus I have chosen to look at TensorFlow.

Back to the issue, the project is currently is written in Objective-C code, as the current API is using C++. However, with the times, I have been more comfortable working in Swift which is why I have wanted to implement an Swift-briding header. I have watched a couple of tutorials in YouTube,

[image]
I hope not to bother you all! Have a nice day! :)

UPDATE 1: I have updated the picture to show that the files do exist, however, the error still occurs! :(

Comment: From the image it seems like project is not properly configured because all files are showing in read that means that files are not there in the project. Open the project from the location where it is using the project file then add the bridging-header file.

Comment: please see other file names that are red its mean it just contained reference of files not actually the project folder not exist.

Comment: @Nishtant Bhindi Oh sorry, I just tried placing them in a folder, I'll take another picture with the files looking fine. :)

Comment: @Abu UI Hassan I've updated them, taking a picture that the project files are included, but still creates the same error...

Comment: it looks like your project path is not valid. please verify it.

Comment: What do you mean, Sir? How should I go about it? :)

Comment: try dragging any image from desktop  to your  project if it generate same error or not ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142235/discussion-between-abu-ul-hassan-and-programming-duders).